# Get feature extraction from YOLOv3

Tags: keras, deep-learning, yolo

I have an implementation of YOLOv3 using mobilenet working (based on https://github.com/Adamdad/keras-YOLOv3-mobilenet). However, I already use mobilenet for feature extraction on other functionalities. I would like to reuse these features extracted from the images to the other models. How can I get them from YOLOv3 model already trained? Is it possible to get the vectors from an intermediate layer of the model?
I've tried this with no success: https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer-feature-extraction
Thanks

Comment: In which step did you fail? What is the failure?

Comment: I've noticed that the weights are different, so I believe it's not possible to reuse the feature vector, right? When I reused the mobilenet part of the yolo model to get the features of the image, the result is different from what I get when I use only mobilenet with imagenet weights.